# Parsing a string to a postgresql timestamp with time zone

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I get a csv file from a system which contains dates in the following format:

05/28/2020 at 23:24:53 (GMT+1000)

I'm currently saving the date in a column of type **character varying(50)** but I want to use **timestamp with time zone** or any other convenient date data type for this.

Please how can I transform this string into a correct date data type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `datestyle = ISO, MDY`, and PostgreSQL should be able to interpret a timestamp of this format correctly. Of course it will protest at `GMT+1000`, but I guess the 1000 were just an example.